# How do I use Vue.js debounce filter?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to use the the `debounce` filter as per the [Vue.js docs](http://vuejs.org/api/filters.html#debounce) so I can prevent firing an Ajax function while the user is typing into an input.  In the past, I have used `setTimeout` to manually prevent sending the request after each letter is entered and to use a resetting delay, but I would like to do it the Vue.js way.

Here is what I tried:

```
<input
v-model="myInput"
v-on="keyup: someAjaxFunction | debounce 500"
>
```

No examples are given in the docs specifically for this filter.  Am I even putting the filter in the right place?

> debounce
>
> this filter only works with v-on
>
> this filter takes one optional argument
>
> Wrap the handler to debounce it for X milliseconds, where X
>   is the argument. Default is 300ms. A debounced handler will be delayed
>   until at least X ms has passed after the call moment; if the handler
>   is called again before the delay period, the delay poriod is reset to
>   X ms.

I have also tried this: ( because the docs mention "Wrap the handler..." )

```
<input
v-model="myInput"
v-on="keyup: debounce( someAjaxFunction, 500 )"
>
```

I could really use an example.

Comment: As a note, this question applies to Vue.js v1; the debounce filter was removed in v2 ([details](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#debounce-Param-Attribute-for-v-model-removed))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your first example is correct:

```
<input v-model="myInput" v-on="keyup: someAjaxFunction | debounce 500">
```

With Vue.js 1.0.0-beta.x, the new syntax is:

```
<input v-model="myInput" on-keyup="someAjaxFunction | debounce 500">
```

Comment: With my first example, I am definitely firing the ajax function on every keyup no matter how fast/slow I type.  Is there something else I could be missing?

Comment: I must have something else wrong; I have tested in jsFiddle and my syntax from the first example works.  http://jsfiddle.net/tpgcsdq9/1/

Answer (score 11):

debounce filter has been [removed](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#debounce-Param-Attribute-for-v-model-removed).

Use [lodash’s debounce](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#debounce) (or possibly throttle) to directly limit calling the expensive method. You can achieve the expected result like this:

```
<input v-on:keyup="doStuff">

methods: {
  doStuff: _.debounce(function () {
    // ...
  }, 500)
}
```

From [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Filters-Outside-Text-Interpolations-removed).

Comment: If we can avoid more 3rd party dependencies, it seems wise. Why not use `Vue.options.filters.debounce` or a manual debounce like this example? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37587800/vue-debounce-a-method#answer-37588776

Comment: As pointed in the answer, debounce support is now removed. If you don't prefer 3rd party library, you can always write it on our own.

Answer (score 5):

Another method is to debounce the **v-model**, instead of calling a method.

You can also just create your own debounce function, without any dependencies:

**Reusable debounce function**

```js
export function debounce (fn, delay) {
  var timeoutID = null
  return function () {
    clearTimeout(timeoutID)
    var args = arguments
    var that = this
    timeoutID = setTimeout(function () {
      fn.apply(that, args)
    }, delay)
  }
}
```

**In your Vue component**

```js
data: () => ({
  textModel: 'something'
}),
watch {
  textModel: debounce(function(newVal) {
    this.searchTextDebounced = newVal;
  }, 500),
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Those who are using Quasar (based on Vue.JS) can use Quasar's own implementation of debounce (maybe Quasar expose Lodash's debounce, I don't know).

Open [debouce section in Q docs](https://quasar.dev/quasar-utils/other-utils#Debounce-Function)