# Vue debounce a method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vue-component

I know Vue.js has functionality built in to debounce on an input field. I have created a slider that fires a method that does not use an input field though, and I was wondering if I can take advantage of the debounce functionality inside of a method.

Is it even possible to use this functionality outside of simply adding a debounce to an input? Or do I need to write my own functionality for this?

I've just tried doing something like this but it does not seem to work:

```
this.$options.filters.debounce(this.search(), 2000);
```

Comment: Doesn't look like there's any easy-to-call debounce function in vue.js - just write one - it's about 5 lines of code and you should be able to find numerous implementations on SO answers or a quick google.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For anyone who is wondering on how to do this. I fixed this by using an awesome little snippet I found:

**Attribute in my data**

```
timer: 0
```

**Debounce functionality**

```
// clears the timer on a call so there is always x seconds in between calls
clearTimeout(this.timer);

// if the timer resets before it hits 150ms it will not run 
this.timer = setTimeout(function(){
    this.search()
}.bind(this), 150);
```

Comment: Man!! This was so helpful after like 2 hours dealing this $hit. Love you man.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is where you got it from, but I read a similar snippet here: https://schier.co/blog/2014/12/08/wait-for-user-to-stop-typing-using-javascript.html

It might be worth giving credit to the author, if that was your source.

Comment: @bjmc got it from a codepen of someone else, this is not the source.

Comment: Would be good if you credited the source.  e.g. the codepen URL

Answer (score 4):

You are put this.search() execution result into debounce, try this:

```
var bufferSearch = Vue.options.filters.debounce(this.search.bind(this), 150);
bufferSearch();
```